# Why do I get this value when printf continues reading and shows the value of the next integer variables

Tags: c, printf

I'm not sure whether I'm asking a silly question.

We know that Printf function prints contiguous block of charaters until it finds a null character. Since, array b does not contain a null character and the format specifier in the 2nd printf command is %s, it prints ‘**xyzx**’ instead of ‘**xyz**’. (I understand that) this is because the output included the value of a, which is x.

However, when I initialise the array a with value ‘**xy**’, the outputs from the 1st and 2nd printf commands become ‘xy**d**’ and ‘xyzxy**d**’ respectively. My question is why are we getting ‘**d**’ from the value of integer int1?

```
int main(void) 
{
int int1 = 100;

char a[2] = "x"; 
char b[3] = "xyz";
printf("1.: %s\n", a);
printf("2.: %s\n", b);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("2.: %s\n", b);` is UB

Comment: I would advise to rather post the code in which you get the `xyd` output

Comment: In the ASCII character set, the character 'd' has a decimal value of 100.

Comment: My question is why is the output string ending with 'd' as a result of printf fundtion reading the adjacent memory.

Comment: "Why does undefined behavior do X" is usually a pointless question from the standpoint of the C language itself.  It is sometimes an interesting way to learn about compilers and low-level machine behavior, but if that's the question you want to ask, you'll need to include a lot more detail about the exact compiler and platform you are using.  Even then, the answer is likely to come down to "that's just what happens to be in that memory location".

Comment: Thank you @DennisSparrow. You're right. It didn't occur to me at all. 
Anyway, why don't you answer the question instead of just making the comment.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I will defer to the more complete answer from KamilCuk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code exhibits undefined behavior. It's not defined what should happen and compiler is allowed to do what it wants.

> why are we getting ‘d’ from the value of integer int1?

Most probably your `int` has 4 bytes and your architecture is little endian. `100` is `0x64`, so it is stored as 4 bytes as `0x64, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00`. Most probably your system uses ASCII and `100` (or `0x64`) is the ascii value of `d`, and the second byte is most probably interpreted as zero terminating character.

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk. I used an online compiler and it actually did convert the number into the corresponding ASCII character.  Printf definitely encountered a null character which made it stop reading further and as you suggested, the second byte has most probably done that job.

Answer (score 0):

`char b[3] = "xyz";` it has to be `char b[4] = "xyz";` to accommodate the terminating nul character.

Comment: You didn't understand my question. My question is why do I get 'd' when it's reading the adjacent memory.

Comment: @Newbir I do understand and I know what the problem is. And you print this d because of the too short array.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I get this value when printf continues reading and shows the value of the next integer variables (?)

The `"%s"` in `printf("2.: %s\n", b);` expects that `b` points to a *string*, a character array with a *null character*.  `char b[3] = "xyz";` lacks a *null character* and is not a *string*.

The result is *undefined behavior*.

In this case, likely code kept printing other nearby memory like `a[]`.

---

Either insure `b` is a *string*

```
//char b[3] = "xyz";
char b[4] = "xyz";  // b[3] is '\0'
printf("2.: %s\n", b);
```

Or print with a precision limit which limits printing.

```
char b[3] = "xyz";
//printf("2.: %s\n", b);
printf("2.: %.*s\n", (int) sizeof b, b);
```